# How to add a complex word to PhpStorm dictionary

Tags: phpstorm

I have a use case where I need to add a complex word to PhpStorm dictionary, but I do not want to add the partial words.
The issue is that combined they form a name of service that I am integrating with (so I need to use that name in code).

Think `PayPal` as example, where `PayPal` should be a valid word, but `Pay` and `Pal` should be invalid.

The reason why I don't want partial words in the dctionary is that they are in polish,
and you should never use non-english words in your code (outside translations directory).

When I am trying to add it to the dictionary I get an error `The word is mixed case. Split it to simple words`
Is there a way to add such complex word to PhpStorm dictionary?

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Natural Languages | Spelling` -- there is a list "Accepted Words" -- try adding such words there. I think it should be all lower case (or the IDE will do it for you -- try it).

Comment: P.S. If you use `Edit` button on "Custom dictionaries" list above that, the IDE will open those files for you. All entries are in A-Z order, lowercase. Not sure if editing it in the IDE will not discard the change when closing the project/IDE (it's when the IDE saves the config files and may overwrite your changes). That's why if you wish to edit any config files, do it when the IDE is closed.

Comment: It didn't work. Both using lowercase and adding it manually to the file is still showing words as incorrect.

Comment: Give a few examples so I can copy+paste and test it here. Maybe letters with extra symbols (like umlauts) do make difference etc. Plain English used to work fine for me in the past (an old project though, 5 or 6 years back -- used for company name which was a made up word) -- It could also be that back then it worked differently (Spellchecker/Grammar subsystem had quite big changes in the past 2 years, they may have changed how that works). No better ideas than that right now.

Comment: There is nothing special, only English characters. The example was PayPal. Not sure if I can share the exact words (legal, trade secrets and stuff). Try something random, like `FoommBarmmBazmm` to use words that do not exist.

Comment: Yep, I can confirm that adding `FoommBarmmBazmm` did not do anything. Must be the changes in the plugin logic (as mentioned earlier) as I'm very sure that it worked differently in the past.

Comment: My only last idea -- what if you make a custom Hunspell dictionary; it _may_ work differently here. Other than that: feel free to make a ticket on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and it may be implemented one day (or another approach suggested by one of the devs)

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166105 -- must be the ticket to watch after -- describes the same issue IMO.